# JavaScript "Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function" associativity question

Tags: javascript

The code is as follows:

```
<body>
    <a href="javascript:;" id="test">hello</a>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", function () {
      test()
    }, false)
    function test() {
      var postTypes = new Array('hello', 'there')
      (function() { alert('hello there') })()
    }
</script>
```

This will throw an:

> "Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function"

If I wrap the anonymous function call/invocation in another set of parentheses it will execute the alert, but still give me an error.  If I put a semicolon after the "var postTypes" definition then it will be completely fine.

I was led to believe that JavaScript does not require semicolons, so I'm making a guess that there is some weird associativity rules of function application that I am not fully understanding. Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Looks almost like you are trying to create both an anonymous function and static function and expecting it to execute as one.  What happens if you remove function()

Answer (score 95, accepted):

JavaScript does require semicolons. It's just that the interpreter will insert them for you on line breaks where possible<sup>*</sup>.

Unfortunately, the code

```
var a = new B(args)(stuff)()
```

does *not* result in a syntax error, so no `;` will be inserted. (An example which can run is

```
var answer = new Function("x", "return x")(function(){return 42;})();
```

To avoid surprises like this, train yourself to always end a statement with `;`.

---

<sup>*</sup> This is just a rule of thumb and not always true. The insertion rule is much more complicated. This [blog page](http://inimino.org/%7Einimino/blog/javascript_semicolons) about semicolon insertion has more detail.

Comment: Or: To avoid surprises like this, train yourself to write clean readable code (which should always apply) and know the general ASI rules... it really is no different than "knowing" how closures in JS work.

Answer (score 19):

Your code experiences a case where the [automatic semicolon insertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion) (ASI) process doesn't happen.

You should never rely on ASI. You should use semicolons to properly separate statements:

```
var postTypes = new Array('hello', 'there'); // <--- Place a semicolon here!!

(function() { alert('hello there') })();
```

Your code was actually trying to invoke the array object.

Comment: One way to fix the issue, but I can't get behind the Crockford-club.

Comment: @pst: Let me rephrase, I'm not in the Crock's-club *at all* :)

Comment: In that case I apologize for the harsh words :(

Comment: I did enjoy the quiz. ASI is indeed terribly confusing with icky-code!

Answer (score 15):

I ran into this problem in [React](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(web_framework)): I tried to [destructure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_(computer_science)#Parallel_assignment) and use a named export when it was a default export, for example:

```js
// module.js
const myFunction = () => null
export default myFunction
```

```js
// component.js
// THIS WAS WRONG:
// import { myFunction } from './module'
// SHOULD BE THIS:
import myFunction from './module'
```

Comment: Exactly my issue here too

Comment: This was also my problem in a VueJs app, which leads me to believe it's more about how to use modules with Webpack.

Comment: The key here is, that you're exporting the function as "default". So you don't hat to put it in curly brackets to deconstruct. If you had exported it like this `export default myFunction` this `import { myFunction } from './module'` would have worked

Answer (score 9):

I got a similar error and it took me a while to realize that in my case I named the array variable *payInvoices* and the function also *payInvoices*. It confused [AngularJS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AngularJS).

Once I changed the name to *processPayments()* it finally worked.

Comment: Same here, I had a variable named `alert` and was trying to call the javascript alert function and it would say 'alert is not a function'. It was trying to call the `alert` variable instead of the actual function

Answer (score 0):

Try to have the function body before the function call in your JavaScript file.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this same error and spent a day and a half trying to find a solution. [Naomi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026891/javascript-uncaught-typeerror-object-is-not-a-function-associativity-question/27118591#27118591) lead me to the solution I needed.

My input (type=button) had an attribute `name` that was identical to a function name that was being called by the onClick event. Once I changed the attribute `name`, everything worked.

```
<input type="button" name="clearEmployer" onClick="clearEmployer();">
```

changed to:

```
<input type="button" name="clearEmployerBtn" onClick="clearEmployer();">
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this error when compiling and bundling TypeScript code with [Webpack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webpack). It compiles `export class AppRouterElement extends connect(store, LitElement){....}` into `let Sr = class extends (Object(wr.connect) (fn, vr)) {....}` which seems wrong because of the missing comma. When bundling with Rollup, no error.