# ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE when saving Mongoose model

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am using Mongoose with Express.js to make a simple todo list app. When I post from the form, I want to save the list item and render a message on the next page. (This will later be replaced with a redirect.) Instead of displaying the message, in Chrome the page will stall until it finally says

> No data received
>   Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data.
>   Reload this webpage.
>   Press the reload button to resubmit the data needed to load the page.
>   Error code: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Firefox says `The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.`

My route looks like this:

```
exports.post = function(req, res) {
    var Item = require('../models/Item')

    new Item({
        content: req.body.content
    }).save(function(){
        res.send('item saved')
    })
}
```

I also tried:

```
var item = new Item({
    content: req.body.content
})

item.save(function(){
    res.send('item saved')
})
```

which does the same thing.

My model looks like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')

var ItemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    content: String
})

var Item = mongoose.model('Item', ItemSchema)
module.exports = Item
```

**How do I get the function in save to execute?**

EDIT:
Here is the client side code:

layout.jade

```
doctype html
html
  head
    meta(charset='utf-8')
    title Listocracy
  body
    block content
```

index.jade

```
extends layout

block content
  h1 Listocracy

  form(method='post', action='/item')
    input(type='text', name='content')
    button(type='submit') Add Item
```

If I pull `res.send` out of the save function it will print the text like it's supposed to. I think the problem is with the save function.

Comment: I forgot to connect to MongoDB.

Answer (score 2):

Try this way:

```
(new Item({
    content: req.body.content
})).save(function(){
    res.send('item saved')
});
```

Nicer way:

```
var item = new Item({
    content: req.body.content
});

item.save(function(err){
    if(!err)
       res.send('item saved')
    // else log and send error message
});
```

Comment: I get `500 TypeError: undefined is not a function` Not sure which function they're referring to because everything is chained, but splitting it brings the ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE problem back.

Comment: Changed the second one to `(item).save(...)`. It now says `500 TypeError: object is not a function` for that line. Is it reading `(item)` as a function?

Comment: @Eva show your client side code

Comment: @Eva does this error occur on client side or on server side?

Comment: Adding semicolons brings back the ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE problem. Apparently, no semicolons is a [syntax error](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4026909/830988). I think the problem is on the server side because the its the response that's empty.

Comment: @Eva see this post: http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/2EDWkwK2Go8[1-25-false]