# Facing a strange issue with angular 5 development vs production code

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, angular5

The following code is working perfectly fine in development mode:
ng serve --open

```
addDriver(driver: any) {
   return fromPromise(this.db.insert('driver', driver));
}
```

But fails with the following error when deployed to production with this error: ng build --prod

> ERROR TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

Getting this error on `this.db.insert`

I am guessing it has something to do with ASI(Automatic Semicolon Insertion)

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As you guessed it correctly, `ASI` rule works only on specific statements as explained [ECMAScript® 2016 Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-rules-of-automatic-semicolon-insertion)

It includes following cases -

- empty statement
- `var` statement
- expression statement
- `do-while` statement
- `continue` statement
- `break` statement
- `return` statement
- `throw` statement

Best solution is to avoid relying on `ASI` as it might not be able to work in all scenarios.

References -

[SO Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026891/javascript-uncaught-typeerror-object-is-not-a-function-associativity-question)

[SO Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this was related to rxjs. Apparently fromPromise does not work correctly in rxjs6. I changed fromPromise to 'from' and it worked.