# Ionic 3 Android Studio emulator won't load myapp

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using ionic with cordova to build an app to which there are no errors visible to the CLI.

I am also using android studio to emulate an app.

Also, I am using chrome inspect feature to verify what is going on with my app, which I noticed theres an error saying the following:

> 'Uncaught TypeError: Object.assign is not a function'.

I am not exactly sure what that means or if that could be the error, I would really appreciate some help with this.

Here's a print screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7POjf.jpg

[image]

Everytime i run my app both on android emulator or my own device using the build APK, my screen turns white after the splash screen and it stays like that forever, also whenever i try to send a push notification to my app, which is the context of my app, nothing happens.

Comment: This might be helpful; https://stackoverflow.com/a/4026909/476747

Comment: is there an easy how to figure this out? i have 5 pages to look for excluding the app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by running ionic cordova emulate android --prod which debugged what exactly was going in, apparently i have one of my pages declared more than once.